# How to do a transaction with Azure.Data.Tables.TableClient?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I can use this TableClient SDK (for Azure Tables) to create, update, retrieve, delete....etc.
But I'm not sure how to do updates (multiple records) in a transaction.

I dont see any documentation of this anywhere (other than the mere mention of doing transactions as a possible design pattern when working with Azure Tables).

How to do this?

Reference to the document: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Data.Tables/

Comment: Have you referred to this? https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Azure.Data.Tables_12.2.0-beta.1/sdk/tables/Azure.Data.Tables/samples/Sample5UpdateUpsertEntities.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer on my own.

Use the TableTransactionActions.
Then call tableclient.SubmitTransaction(actionsList)

Comment: There is a example at https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/tables/Azure.Data.Tables/tests/samples/Sample6_TransactionalBatchAsync.cs